# Partition after installation

Tags: partitioning

I have installed ubuntu 15.04 by erasing hard disk.During installation, I haven't done the partition.So, can anyone tell me how to do it now?
i'm attaching screenshot of gparted [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrT0u.png)

Comment: What do you mean? If you installed the system in auto mode, it has made partitioning for you.

Comment: i have used the option "erase the disk and install ubuntu15.04" after that i was not asked for partition

Comment: Good. You have everything done. Nothing to worry about. You could manually create partitions, but if you want one system, default install is quite good.

Comment: @Pilot6 can u please tell me how to create partitions manually.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: You have a good standard partitioning. There is no need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted, depending what you want to do. It has a gui, so it is very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Alright, that partition table is quite ugly. I'd make it different.
If you want to apply the changes that I'm going to suggest, you need to start a live session of Ubuntu, like you did for installing the OS on your system.

After launching the live session, open the dash and start gparted.

Now, I don't like two things in your partition table:

1- The swap partition is HUGE for its purpose;

2- You have a large root(/) partition without a separate home (/home) partition.

How to fix those things:

1- Open gparted from a live session;

2- Select the swap partition and resize it to a maximum of 2048Mib (the equivalent of 2Gib). To do that, there's a button in the top menu (view image):
[image]

NOTE: do not use my partition table.

3- Resize the root partition (mount point /) to something like 25Gib (it depends on your needs, it can be way larger if you want).

4- Now, with the free space remaining, create a new primary-ext4 partition with mount point set as /home.

Now, you'll have a standard partition table, with a root partition, a home partition and a swap partition.

Comment: How did you find out OP's partitioning? Or is it a re-post of some answer?

Comment: He attached a screenshot in the question.

Comment: And where it is now? I do not see it in edit history either. EFI is mount a wrong way BTW.

Comment: The last word 'here' is a link to the screenshot.

Comment: OK. But your screenshot is quite different. OP's partitioning is good.

Comment: I never said that he should follow my partition table, please read the post. I don't think a partition with +7Gib of swap is any good.

Comment: No harm in this swap. It matches ram. Hibernation will work.